# Disable one dropdown when a specific option of another is selected

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two dropdowns in one form. The first contains those options:

```
String[] decisions = {"acceptée", "rejettée"};
```

When "rejettée" is selected, I would like to disable the second dropdown.

Here is the relevant code of the two dropdowns:

```
<p:selectOneMenu required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez choisir une decision" id="dec" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />            
</p:selectOneMenu>  
<p:selectOneMenu  id="etat" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.etat}">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.etats}" />   
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h:outputLabel for="dec" value="Decision : " />
    <p:selectOneMenu required="true"
        requiredMessage="veuillez choisir une decision" id="dec"
        value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />
        <p:ajax update="etat" event="change"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:message for="dec" display="icon" />

    <h:outputLabel for="etat" value="Etat : " />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="etat" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.etat}" disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée'}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.etats}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:message for="etat" display="icon" />
```

To set to some default value on change, try this:

```
<h:outputLabel for="dec" value="Decision : " />
<p:selectOneMenu required="true"
    requiredMessage="veuillez choisir une decision" id="dec"
    value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}" valueChangeListener="#{editCommandController.vclistener}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />
    <p:ajax />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="dec" display="icon" />

<h:outputLabel for="etat" value="Etat : " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="etat" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.etat}" disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision ne 'rejettée'}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.etats}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="etat" display="icon" />
```

And then in the backing bean add the selectItem if not already present otherwise you can skip it:

```
public static List<SelectItem> etats = new ArrayList<SelectItem>() { {
    add(new SelectItem("Cheese", "Cheese"));
    add(new SelectItem("Pickle", "Pickle"));
    add(new SelectItem("Mustard", "Mustard"));
    add(new SelectItem("Lettuce", "Lettuce"));
}};

public void vclistener(ValueChangeEvent e){
    if(e.getNewValue().equals("rejettée")){
        EditCommandController.etats.add(0, new SelectItem("Ketchup", "Ketchup"));
        myCom.setEtat("Ketchup");
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("etat");
}

public List<SelectItem> getEtats() {
    return etats;
}

public void setEtats(List<SelectItem> etats) {
    EditCommandController.etats = etats;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your responses, unfortunately it  makes me a red line inder this : #{editCommandController.myCom.decision ne empty and editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée'}

Comment: Just remove the first `and` condition altogether. It makes no utter sense.

Comment: I replaced ne empty by not empty but same problem

Comment: Remove it altogether. You don't need it at all. Just `disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée'}"` is what you need.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for the pointer, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I only leave disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée'}" but it works only when the value of the first combo is "rejettée" from the begining, and when I change its value the second combo is not activated

Comment: please, when the second dropdown is disabled I want to set it to a fixed value, How can I achieve this?, thanks

Comment: updated the answer. See if it works for you. It can also be done using javascript if thats an option.

Comment: @user1581868, please mark the answer accepted if it has worked for you. See also [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)